# How to easily change pixel color of a texture in the fragment shader? (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, multidimensional-array, fragment-shader

My goal is to make simple sand simulation using c++ and OpenGL. Right now my plan is to have a **2d array** of pixel colors and a **texture** the same size. To simulate sand I will update the array accordingly to the sand coordinates and where it has to travel. I'm thinking of **sending the 2d array** of pixels to the **fragment shader** and update the texture there with colors on the array. **The problem** is that I can't find a way to change the pixel color on the texture.

So how do I change the color of the pixel at certain coordinates on texture?
Is doing this even practical? If, no what are the other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Did u mean for texture coordinates? You can change only fragment color output. You have also the texture color but you can use only for frgament output.

```
gl_FragColor = tex + vec4(0.5, 0, 0, 1)*tex.a;
```

for blending operation

Anyway here's more info about the frag https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Other_outputs